# Scroll Animation React

Tags: javascript, css, animation, scroll, parallax

I have designed a website with some advanced animations.
I'd like to make the same animations. I have already code every animations with keyframes but i'd like them to be smooth and that they depend on the scroll.
I don't really know what library compatible with react i could use because gsap doesn't handle advanced scroll animation.
I saw scrollMagic but it seems a bit deprecated...

Here's the figma link:
https://www.figma.com/file/D6idKf4D5VkmK280doIH6v/Untitled?node-id=0%3A1

I also saw this website :
https://www.sleepiest.com
I think the library they are using could suit.

If anyone knows a library it would help me a lot.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they are using swiper: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper.
I opened the [CSS](https://www.sleepiest.com/assets/css/main.css?ver=1.0.18) and found classes like `.swiper-slide`.
The german in your figma is not correct by the way.

Comment: Could you add a possible example of using classes like `.swiper-slide` for this specific scenario? That helps this answer be more useful for future SO goers in search of Scroll Animations in React.

Comment: I have never used swiper, so I do not know how to use this css class. The documentation can be found here: https://swiperjs.com/